# Unable to create suitable graphics device?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I've been following the [Eye of the Dragon tutorial](http://xnagpa.net/rpgtutorials.html), which is basicly a guide to making a 2D RPG game, **obviously**.

I recently finished the tutorial about making pop up screens in the menu and changed the screen to load as a full screen.

Whenever I try and load the game it just goes black and my mouse sits there. I cannot change out of it other then with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>. Once i do that it says **No suitable graphics card found, unable to create graphics device**.

I read somewhere about XNA not allowing more then one screen when any one of them is **full screen**. but it wasnt very informative. Anyone have any ideas whats going on and/or how to fix this?

Just incase if this helps this is the code for the graphics device:

```
public Game1()
{
    graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 900;
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 768;
    graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
    this.Window.Title = "Eyes of the Dragon";
    Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
}
```

Comment: I suspect you're getting the "no suitable graphics card" error *because* you're pressing ctrl-alt-delete. This is because you're switching from the **Default Desktop** to the **Winlogon Desktop** ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682573(v=vs.85).aspx)). Your game runs on the default desktop, and while that desktop is inactive, it cannot access the graphics device - hence the error.

Comment: Try creating a fresh game using the default XNA game template (the "cornflower blue" screen, add the code for full screen (what you've posted) and see if that works. (Is your problem with your full-screen code? Or is it elsewhere? Try to reproduce it with as little code as possible.)

Comment: Try adding 'GraphicsGevice.GraphicsDeviceInformation.PresentationParameters.FullScreenRefreshRateInHz = 60;'

Comment: I'm actually a bit confused by the black screen at first. Sounds like something gets stuck. It doesn't happen in windowed mode?

Comment: @AndrewRussell Hitting Ctrl+Alt+Del shouldn't just crash the game. It will (at least did so under XP; haven't done DirectX for ages) invalidate the context, but XNA should handle all that stuff on its own, without any noticeable impact.

Comment: @Mario Indeed. Although my thinking is along the lines of: I *think* you get this error if you try and *create* the graphics device while the desktop is inactive (as opposed to it *going* inactive and invalidating a context that already exists). But I've not researched it in enough detail to be 100% sure. It does lead me to wonder what else is going on in the OP's code.

Comment: Ah, yes, that might be true, but even then there has to be some reason for it getting stuck before doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your resolution is right and supported by both your graphics card and your monitor? To me it sounds like that's not the case.

What happens if you pick 1024x768? You can't just pick any (fullscreen) resolution you want and expect it to work.

If you need such an odd resolution for whatever reason, use transformations to properly scale the output.

Some cards might be able to still properly transform/scale this through drivers. E.g. Nvidia cards got a setting for upscaling (whether it's done by the monitor or graphics card). If it's done by the card, I think it will accept pretty much any resolution (which doesn't mean you should do it).

Comment: XNA is supposed to automatically fall-back to an available resolution, if you select something invalid - hence the "`Preferred*`". (Although valid modes can be enumerated with `GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.SupportedDisplayModes`).

Comment: Ah okay, so that's essentially built in. I guess the same would be true for refresh rate?

Comment: Yes, I think so.